# TextOptions.DisplayColorEmoji of a button in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Here what i can do in XAML in windows phone 8 app

```
<Button Content="&#x1f3a7;"
FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
TextOptions.DisplayColorEmoji="False"/>
```

I want to set DisplayColorEmoji of a button to false in code behind programatically in C#
like doing this for an example

```
Button button = new Button();
button.FontSize = 25;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Windows.Media;
...
button.SetValue(TextOptions.DisplayColorEmojiProperty, false);
```

Calling the method `SetValue` should help. `TextOptions.DisplayColorEmojiProperty` is a DependencyProperty.

Comment: @MGhanem if this solves your problem, remember to set it as the answer to your question.

Comment: @Nacimota i tried to mark it but i must have 15 reputation at least to do so, so i just made a comment.

Comment: @MGhanem ah that's right; I forgot about that restriction.